# SHOW COLUMNS, Dynamic variables, INSERT INTO.. implode?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, html-table, http-post

This form is getting columns names from table `pracownicy`. It's dynamic because these are names of applications that a new employee is going to use on his computer when he start working for our company.
I've got another form for adding columns in table `pracownicy` because numbers of applications that employees are using is increasing.
This form is for supervisors of every department for announcing us about a new employee coming to work. I have a problem with inserting data back to mysql.
How can I POST and put into `insert into` data from this form ? Numbers of variables (applications from "SHOW COLUMNS") is changing every time I'm adding some new application to the database so I can't use static variables.
Show columns, `$query = Values (Implode)` ???

```
echo '<form action="formularz.php" method="POST">
<table  border=0 class=\"odd gradeX\">
<tr bgcolor=#ffdddd>
<td>Imię i nazwisko:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="imieinazwisko"></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor=#ddddff>
<td>Dział:</td>
<td align=center><select name="dzial">
    <option value = "LCL">LCL
    <option value = "NVOCC">NVOCC
    <option value = "ZA">ZA
    <option value = "ZAM">ZAM
    <option value = "ZLR">ZLR
    <option value = "ZR">ZR
    <option value = "ZT">ZT
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor=#ffdddd>
<td>Telefon:</td>
<td align=center><select name="telefon">
    <option value = "Stacjonarny">Stacjonarny
    <option value = "Blackberry">Blackbery
    <option value = "Blackberry + Stacjonarny">Blackbery + Stacjonarny
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor=#ddddff>
<td>Komputer:</td>
<td align=center><select name="komputer">
    <option value = "Laptop">Laptop
    <option value = "Laptop + Iplus">Laptop + Iplus
    <option value = "Stacjonarny">Stacjonarny
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor=#ffdddd>
<td> <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Data rozpoczęcia pracy: </td><td><input type="text" 
name ="data" id="datepicker"/></p></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor=#ddddff>
<td>Oprogramowanie:</td><td></td></tr>


<tr bgcolor=#ddddff>';



$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM pracownicy") or    die(mysql_error());

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
if($row[0] == 'id' || $row[0] == 'imieinazwisko' || $row[0] == 'dzial' 
|| $row[0] == 'telefon' || $row[0] == 'komputer' || $row[0] == oprogramowanie' 
||          $row[0] == 'data')
continue;
        echo '<td bgcolor=#ddddff>'.$row[0].'<br />';


if (stripos($row[0], "uprawnienia") !== false) {
echo '<td bgcolor=#ddddff><p><a class=podpowiedz href=#>   
<input type="text" name="'.$row[0].'">
<span>Uprawnienia typu "stanowisko" lub "jak ktoś"</span></a></p>          
</td></tr>';
        }
        else
        { 
echo '<td bgcolor=#ddddff align=center><select name="'.$row[0].'">
<option value = "Nie">Nie
<option value = "Tak">Tak
</td>
</tr>';
}

}
//echo '</select></form>';
echo '

<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="zapisz" value="Zapisz"></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</form></center>';`

if(isset($_POST['zapisz'])) 
{
$imieinazwisko = trim($_POST['imieinazwisko']);
$dzial = trim($_POST['dzial']);
$telefon = trim($_POST['telefon']);
$komputer = trim($_POST['komputer']);
$data = trim($_POST['data']);
???  $rowSrray = trim($_POST[$row[0]]);           ---????

??? $query = "INSERT INTO `pracownicy` VALUES (NULL , '$imieinazwisko' , '$dzial',
'$telefon' , '$komputer' , '$data', ".implode(', ', $_POST[$row['0']]).")"; ---???
```

Comment: So you ad a new column for every new application that is in use in your company? That’s messy, _normalize_ your data structure.

Comment: You're missing a quote here `$row[0] == oprogramowanie'`. Also it isn't very clear where's the problem ? If you want to know how to insert data in a database there are tons of questions/answers on SO.

Comment: if($row[0] == 'id' || $row[0] == 'imieinazwisko' || $row[0] ==  'dzial' || $row[0] == 'telefon' || $row[0] == 'komputer' || $row[0]  == oprogramowanie' ||  $row[0] == 'data')    <- it's only for exclude static parts from "SHOW COLUMNS" so i can insert data only to "applications" fields.. I fixed missing quota but it's still not working.. I don't know how to coolect "<select name">" from form and "value" and inster it into mysql query..

Answer (score 1):

You should seriously think about changing your database structure. It is not a good idea to dynamically add columns to a table in a running database applcation.

Your request is not an unusual one, but in most cases people solve the problem by having one column specifying the actual application and then a few more where they put in the information regarding the chosen application (in form of char, integer odr date fields). This has the advantage of keeping the table structure small and manageable but being very flexible at the same time. Tables with too many (mostly unused) columns are considered *ugly* or *messy* because they slow down your SQL server unnecessarily.

So, maybe something like the following might help you:

```
CREATE TABLE applications (apid int auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, apname varchar(64), apdescription nvarchar(1024))

-- "pracownicy" --> users?
CREATE TABLE users (usid int auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, usname varchar(64), usfirstname varchar(64), ustel varchar(64) null, uscomputer varchar(64) null)

-- and then the linking element: app2usr
CREATE TABLE app2usr (auaid int, auuid int, auinfo varchar(64) null, auactive int DEFAULT 1, PRIMARY KEY(auaid,auuid))
```

Now you can have as many (or as few) applications as you like per user without ever having to change the table layout. The only thing you will have to update when a new application pops up is the applications table which contains one line per application.

A typical query for getting all the application information for one user might be

```
SELECT usname,usfirstname,apname,auinfo 
  FROM users INNER JOIN app2usr ON auuid=usid
             INNER JOIN applications ON apid=auaid 
  WHER auactive>0
```

When it comes to UPDATING or INSERTING new information you will then create (or delete) records in `app2usr` accordingly. I know this is only a very rough description to get you on "the right path" ...

**Edit:**

For **collecting** all your application **input fields** from the **form** you need to find out at first which applications are to be assigned to the user. Maybe you have used checkboxes or multiple select elements for this purpose?

- In the first case you can scan the $_POST array for valid application names (against a list which you should get from the server first, with something like `SELECT apid,apname FROM applications`).
- In the second case the select element will have put an array of IDs into the $_POST array which correspond to the selected applications - *IF* you have set up the select box in that way in the first place. Something like `<select name="apps" multiple="multiple"><option value="1">Application1</option>...</select>`, where you get the values and the `Application1` name from the applications table, should do the trick.